# How to use python ArgumentParser on databricks?

Tags: python, databricks

I would like to run my python code by passing some arguments using ArgumentParser, the parser code is like:

```
def parse_args(argv):
    global Settings, COST_PP, COST_BP, COST_NP, COST_PN, COST_BN, COST_NN

    desc = "..."
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=desc)

   parser.add_argument("infile", action="store")
   parser.add_argument("-o", "--outfile", action="store", dest="outfile")
   args = parser.parse_args(argv)


def main():
    global Settings

    parse_args(sys.argv[1:])

    print("\t".join(sys.argv[1:]))
    logging.info("SETTINGS:")
    for k, v in Settings.items():
       logging.info("\t\t" + str(k) + ":\t" + str(v)) ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

But I got an error like this:

```
usage: PythonShell.py [-h] [-o OUTFILE] [-alg ALGORITHM] [-cL CLASS_LIST]
                  [-n RUNS] [-tf TRAIN_FRAC] [-cs COST_SET]
                  [-ms MULT_STRAT] [--log LOG_FILE] [-d]
                  infile
PythonShell.py: error: unrecognized arguments: 0 50000 1916 
a91f477cb4de44dfa5d1f3dd01f8f606 2.2.0
To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.
```

I wonder how to run the code correctly in the databricks notebook? Appreciate any help!

Comment: It would be helpful to add the command you ran that gave this error.

Comment: All the code are in the same notebook, I put the first two functions in two different cells and they compile ok. Then I put "if __name__ == '__main__': main()" in a seperate cell and hit run button and get the error.

Comment: This doesn't appear to have anything to do with `argparse`, because you never call `parser.parse_args()`.

Comment: Maybe spend some time with [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) first? There are examples there that show you how to work with `argparse`.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I found to pass Parameters to Databricks Python script/job from Azure Data Factory was to use shlex:

```
    import argparse, shlex
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--arg1', type=str, required=True)
    parser.add_argument('--arg2', type=str, required=True)
    args = parser.parse_args(shlex.split(" ".join(sys.argv[1:])))
```

Arguments are passed by Databicks as: ["script", "--arg1 val", "--arg1 val"]
while argparse expects argument names and values splitted: ["script", "--arg1", "val", "--arg1", "val"].

We first concatenate all arguments as one string and then split it with shlex to get the correct list to pass to the parse_args.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similair issue. Even when I tried to run the most basic example of [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html). But you can run argument parser in databricks in two ways:

1. Pass the arguments in an array:

   ```
   import argparse
   parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Process some integers.')
   parser.add_argument('integers', metavar='N', type=int, nargs='+',
                       help='an integer for the accumulator')
   parser.add_argument('--sum', dest='accumulate', action='store_const',
                       const=sum, default=max,
                       help='sum the integers (default: find the max)')
   ## normally you can now do: parser.parse_args(), instead do this:
   parser.parse_args(['23', '35'])
   ```
2. Place the code in a seperate notebook and run that notebook from you current notebook with the %run command. Explained [here](https://forums.databricks.com/questions/176/how-do-i-pass-argumentsvariables-to-notebooks.html)